# Is it true that every bottom-up DP has a corresponding top-down realization?

Tags: recursion, iteration, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve this [Longest Palindromic Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/) problem which returns the longest palindromic substring in the given string `s`. I am supposed to solve this problem with DP in `O(n^2)` time. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        # DP
        h = {} #memoization
        
        def dp(i, j): # DP algorithm to compute if the substring s[i:j+1] is palindrome
            nonlocal s, h
            if (i,j) in h: return h[(i, j)]
            else:
                if j - i <= 1:
                    f = s[i] == s[j]
                else:
                    f = dp(i+1, j-1) and s[i] == s[j]
                h[(i, j)] = f
                return f

        res,start, end = 0, 0, 0
        
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(i,len(s)): # All possible substring
                if (i,j) in h: temp = h[(i,j)]
                else: temp = dp(i, j)
                if temp == True and j - i + 1 > res:
                    res = j-i+1
                    start = i
                    end = j
        return s[start:end+1]
```

This solution gets Time Limit Exceeded, I am not sure where can be optimized in my algorithm. Then I checked the solution and found one bottom-up DP algorithm:

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
  int n = s.length();
  String res = null;
    
  boolean[][] dp = new boolean[n][n];
    
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
      dp[i][j] = s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j) && (j - i < 3 || dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
            
      if (dp[i][j] && (res == null || j - i + 1 > res.length())) {
        res = s.substring(i, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
    
  return res;
}
```

How can I modify my top-down algorithm to compete against the above bottom-up algorithm? Is it true that every bottom-up DP has a corresponding top-down method with the same time complexity?

Comment: It could well be the case. But for this case, you can do just fine w/o DP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know this problem can be solved without using DP, but I am learning DP. Specifically, I want a solution that is top-down DP.

Comment: Post another DP version. It works but not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is top-down DP approach, and but it is *not very efficient.* compared with bottom-up or straight one that I've posted earlier.

```
 def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
     if not s: return s
     res = ''
     n = len(s)
     dp = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
     mx  = 0
     for j in range(n):
         for i in range(0, j+1):
             dp[i][j] = ((s[i] == s[j]) and ((j - i <= 2) or dp[i+1][j-1]))
             if dp[i][j]:
                if (j-i+1) > mx:
                    mx  = j-i+1
                    res = s[i:j+1]
     return res
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask why this top-down is worse than the bottom-up implementation? I thought they should be the same?

Comment: There is good theory behind that. But I will suggest you post another question for it.  "One question one Post."